# Number of tried for a favorable result

Tags: binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I am new to statistics so I apologize for the simplicity of my question.

I have a bag with 27 numbers inside; I will pull one number out until I get number 17. THe numbers will be returned to the bag after every try so the prob of success will always be 1/27.

I am trying to determine on average how many pulls I will need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harvey explained the logic.  But the name of the distribution you're interested in is the geometric distribution.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I started with. But was using an old edition of Walpole which did not have much information on it.

Answer (score 3):

On average, you need 27 tries.

Comment: It would be interesting to expand that response a little bit, especially to show how you get this result.

Comment: @chl: Yessir! The OP asks for $E(N)$ where $N\ge1$ is the date of the first success in a series of independent trials, each with probability $p=1/27$ of success. The event $[N\ge n+1]$ corresponds to the $n$ first trials being unsuccessful, hence (by independence) $P(N\ge n+1)=(1-p)^n$. Now, for every nonnegative integer valued $N$, $E(N)$ is the sum of $P(N\ge n+1)$ from $n=0$ to $+\infty$. For every complex number $a$ such that $|a|<1$, the sum of $a^n$ from $n=0$ to $+\infty$ is $1/(1-a)$. For $a=1-p$, one gets $E(N)=1/p=27$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to think backwards. What is the chance of NOT choosing 17? That chance is 26/27. What is the chance of not choosing 17 twice in a row? The answer is (26/27)*(26/27). How about three times in a row?  The answer is (26/27)*(26/27) *(26/27). More generally, the answer is (26/27)^K, where K is the number of times you try and "^" means "to the power of". You can compute that probability for various values of K, and find a value of K that gives an answer close to 0.50.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I made a presumption before where after 27 tries it would then stop searching thus giving a bias on the results

```
# Number of repeats
iters = 10000
results = rep(0,iters)
# Ball to search for
searchNumber = 27

for(i in 1:iters) {
    # A random permutation:
    balls = sample(1:27,iters, replace=T)

    # Number of times picking a ball
    tries = 1

    while(tries<iters) {
        if(balls[tries] == searchNumber) {
            results[i] = tries
            break
        }
        tries = tries + 1
    }
}

hist(results, breaks=100, col="blue")
mean(results)
```

Edit: with a mean / average of around 27

*Edit: In my example we are looking for 27 but the results are the same, it could be any number between 1-27*

Comment: Why limit tries to 27?

Comment: I was thinking that there had to be some kind of limit and that after checking 27 times that you would stop. But thats a presumption that I probably should not have made.. What would you suggest?